# How to I populate a treeView from a mouse click on an item in listView in C#?

Tags: c#, listview, ms-access, treeview

How to I populate a treeView from a mouse click on an item in listView in C#? Data in the listView is read from an access database.

Answer (score 0):

Use BeforeExpand event of TreeView and utilize TreeViewCancelEventArgs.

```
 e.Node.Nodes.Add(...)
```